# SVG Icon Code Support in WordPress Custom Html Widget? Not Working

Tags: widgets, svg

I am Trying to Add SVG Icon Code in Custom HTML Widget, it is not working showing following error **"There is 1 error which must be fixed before you can save."**. How we can fix it without plugin.

```
<ul>
<li>
                        
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-whatsapp" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M13.601 2.326A7.854 7.854 0 0 0 7.994 0C3.627 0 .068 3.558.064 7.926c0 1.399.366 2.76 1.057 3.965L0 16l4.204-1.102a7.933 7.933 0 0 0 3.79.965h.004c4.368 0 7.926-3.558 7.93-7.93A7.898 7.898 0 0 0 13.6 2.326zM7.994 14.521a6.573 6.573 0 0 1-3.356-.92l-.24-.144-2.494.654.666-2.433-.156-.251a6.56 6.56 0 0 1-1.007-3.505c0-3.626 2.957-6.584 6.591-6.584a6.56 6.56 0 0 1 4.66 1.931 6.557 6.557 0 0 1 1.928 4.66c-.004 3.639-2.961 6.592-6.592 6.592zm3.615-4.934c-.197-.099-1.17-.578-1.353-.646-.182-.065-.315-.099-.445.099-.133.197-.513.646-.627.775-.114.133-.232.148-.43.05-.197-.1-.836-.308-1.592-.985-.59-.525-.985-1.175-1.103-1.372-.114-.198-.011-.304.088-.403.087-.088.197-.232.296-.346.1-.114.133-.198.198-.33.065-.134.034-.248-.015-.347-.05-.099-.445-1.076-.612-1.47-.16-.389-.323-.335-.445-.34-.114-.007-.247-.007-.38-.007a.729.729 0 0 0-.529.247c-.182.198-.691.677-.691 1.654 0 .977.71 1.916.81 2.049.098.133 1.394 2.132 3.383 2.992.47.205.84.326 1.129.418.475.152.904.129 1.246.08.38-.058 1.171-.48 1.338-.943.164-.464.164-.86.114-.943-.049-.084-.182-.133-.38-.232z"/>
</svg>                      
                    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: That's not enough information to go by. what is this custom code you inserted into the widget? Did you copy paste it from somewhere? if you copy pasted, did you first try pasting it into notepad and making sure the copied code is correct and doesn't include unwanted content and characters?

Comment: I Mentioned Code in Question's Description.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When we add the above code in the Widget, widget not accepting this code showing following error "There is 1 error which must be fixed before you can save."

Comment: When we add the above code in the Widget, widget not accepting this code showing following error "There is 1 error which must be fixed before you can save."

Answer (score 0):

I changed the viewBox code to a lowercase letter b and solved it by making the letter B lowercase.
or use widget block.